# Is it possible to set text of TextView with a method of ViewModel that returns String?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-mvvm

Is it possible to change text of TextView with a method that returns String?

For training purposes i created this `ViewModel` class, it puts `User` object into `List<User> mUserList` and i wonder if i can set first names of this users as text of TextView with a method of ViewMode. I get binding error, can this be fixed using a method that returns String without using @BindingAdapter annotation?

Edit: When i set `android:text="@{viewmodel.userList.toString()}"` it does not return a binding error but it returns String presentation of User objects. But when i use `android:text="@{viewmodel.getUserFirstNames()}"` i get a binding error. Why does this happen?

```
public class UsersViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private List<User> mUserList;

    public List<User> getUserList() {
        if (mUserList == null) {
            mUserList = loadUsers();
        }
        return mUserList;
    }

    /**
     * Dummy Method to fake web service
     *
     * @return list of users
     */
    private List<User> loadUsers() {
    // do something to load users
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName("John");
    user.setLastName("Adams");
    userList.add(user);

    user = new User();
    user.setFirstName("Lucy");
    user.setLastName("Adams");
    userList.add(user);

    return userList;

    }


    @NonNull
    private String getUserFirstNames() {
        if (mUserList != null && mUserList.size() > 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("First Names:\n");
            for (User user : mUserList) {
                sb.append(user.getFirstName() + "\n");
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }

        return "empty";
    }
}
```

In MainActivity i fake to load data with
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        UsersViewModel usersViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UsersViewModel.class);
        usersViewModel.getUserList();
        activityMainBinding.setViewmodel(usersViewModel);
    }
}
```

In layout i wonder if it's possible to set text of TextView with ViewModel class

```
    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.tutorial1basics.viewmodel.UsersViewModel" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_users"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.getUserFirstNames()}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: You want to use ObservableField<String> for it https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField

Comment: I've just started learning MVVM and i was wondering if it's possible with a method, not with static @BindingAdapter, LiveData, or ObservableField<String>. It's just for educational purposes, i just wonder if it's possible or not?

Comment: you can use MVP from this link
 [this] (https://medium.com/@cervonefrancesco/model-view-presenter-android-guidelines-94970b430ddf)

Comment: Yes its possible.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's not possible. When i set             `android:text="@{viewmodel.userList.toString()}"` it does not return a binding error but it returns String presentation of User objects. But when i use  `android:text="@{viewmodel.getUserFirstNames()}"` i get a binding error.

Comment: You can extend your model with BaseObservable.

Comment: @MayurPatel would you minding providing a snipper for it?

Comment: @Thracian Yes sure.

Comment: @Thracian  You may get more from this blog https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-data-binding-f9f9d3afc761

Answer (score 1):

You want to extends your model with BaseObservable.

**Like :**

```
public class Post extends BaseObservable{
    @SerializedName("userId")
    @Expose
    private Integer userId;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("body")
    @Expose
    private String body;

    @Bindable
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userId);
    }

    @Bindable
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.id);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.title);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.body);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was actually wondering if it's possible with a class that extends `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel`. But as far as i understand data should be some kind of **observable** to be able to set text of with a method or as a field, right? If i extend `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel` class then i should use Observable<String> and getter method, right?

Comment: My mistake was to set `getUserFirstNames()` method as private. I set it to public and it works now. You can set text of TextView with a method that returns String. The purpose of extending android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel class is for data to survive device rotation since ViewModel class has it's own life cycle. However you can't notify changes on User without LiveData or ObservableField.

Comment: Yes its totally depend on your operation that what kind of work you need.

Comment: @Thracian maybe you can help me in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285153/how-to-bind-a-view-model-variable-with-custom-class-type